# Arithmetic operation on Column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to subtract value from column value like below

```
transactionRDD.select(
.when((col("transactionId") === col("uuid") ) , 60 - minute(col("transactionTime")))
)
```

This is not allowing me as it is a column.
Anyway to achieve this? I tried to Instanceof[Int] it is still not allowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract a value with column as `60 - minute(col("transactionTime"))`, you should have both as a column. So to make `60` as a `column` value you can use `lit` which creates a `column` the  with literal value
You need to add the `otherwise` part as well otherwise it returns `null`

```
transactionRDD.select(
.when((col("transactionId") === col("uuid") ) , lit(60) - minute(col("transactionTime")))
  .otherwise(0)
)
```

Comment: I have otherwise part., but i want to subtract "transactionTime" from 60., that is not working since `minute(col("transactionTime"))` still Column object

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you